# How to check if input is a natural number in Python?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, input, numbers

Right now I'm trying to make a simple tic-tac-toe game, and while user chooses the sector of the board for their next move I need to check if the input is a *single-digit natural number*. I don't think just making a `['1','2','3'...'9']` list and calling an in statement for it is the most optimal thing. Could you suggest anything?

Comment: Now I at least know all the possible ways. Thanks everyone for the answers!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check if a string, `x`, is a single digit natural number by checking if the string contains digits and the integer equivalent of those digits is between 1 and 9, i.e.

`x.isdigit() and 1 <= int(x) <= 9`

Also, if `x.isdigit()` returns false, `int(x)` is never evaluated due to the expression using `and` (it is unnecessary as the result is already known) so you won't get an error if the string is not a digit.

Comment: Works too, but just checking for len == 1 works the same way.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#len) and [`str.isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit):

```
>>> x = '1'
>>> len(x) == 1 and x.isdigit() and x > '0'
True
>>> x = 'a'
>>> len(x) == 1 and x.isdigit() and x > '0'
False
>>> x = '12'
>>> len(x) == 1 and x.isdigit() and x > '0'
False
```

Alternative: using [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#len) and chained comparisons:

```
>>> x = '1'
>>> len(x) == 1 and '1' <= x <= '9'
True
>>> x = 'a'
>>> len(x) == 1 and '1' <= x <= '9'
False
>>> x = '12'
>>> len(x) == 1 and '1' <= x <= '9'
False
```

Comment: Oh, I completely forgot about len. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use

```
>>> natural = tuple('123456789')
>>> '1' in natural
True
>>> 'a' in natural
False
>>> '12' in natural
False
```

Checking for membership in a small tuple you initialize once is *very* efficient, a `tuple` in particular over a `set` since it's optimized for small numbers of items. Using `len` and `isdigit` is overkill.

Comment: Well, I just wanted to know a more compact way of checking without the need to print the whole natural number row.

Comment: @Owlythesova but it's the best way to do it and very fast. Checking a `tuple` is also faster than a `list` (python can optimize this membership check since tuples are immutable). Two function calls has to be slower but I haven't made any timings

Comment: @Owlythesova, If you don't want to list them manually, you can use `string.digits[1:]`

Comment: @falsetru I thought of this as well but it's actually more effort

Comment: @jamylak: It may be worthwhile to do some timing tests, but I guess timings will vary significantly across the various Python implementations. `isdigit()` (in standard Python) is quite fast as it's implemented in C, using C's own `isdigit()`, which itself is quite efficient, at least for ASCII, since it (typically) uses an array of char types indexed by byte value. Python `len()` is also very fast, as it's just an attribute lookup - all built-in Python container objects store their length as an attribute.

Comment: For the curious, you can see the C source for `isdigit()` at http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Objects/stringobject.c?view=markup lines 3393-3421

Comment: @PM2Ring You are going too far into this, this code is not the bottleneck.

Comment: @jamylak: What bottleneck? I agree that for this particular application (validating strings from user input), arguing over timing is ludicrous. But for general application, I suspect that `len(x) == 1 and x.isdigit()` would be faster than your tuple-based test.

Comment: That would make sense but it is ludicrous to think that would really ever make a difference

Answer (score 2):

Following on console could help :

```
>>> x=1
>>> x>0 and isinstance(x,int)
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Although there are many answers for your question , but , with all due respect, i believe there are some bugs that may happen through using them.

One of them is that using `x.isdigit()` , this works! but just for strings!!. but what if we wanna check another types such as float? and another problem is that using this method will not work for some numbers such as 12.0. right!. it's a natural number but pyhton will find this as a float. so i think we can check natural numbers by using this function :

```
def checkNatNum(n):
    if str(n).isdigit() and float(n) == int(n) and int(n) > 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I ensure you this will do the process fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why are people pushing this to next level.
Simply for natural number you can write,

```
int(x) > 0
```

And for the range issue:

```
0 < int(x) <= 9
```

Obviously numbers lying within the range are natural numbers.

Comment: if x was eqaul to something like 12.45 , your code won't help any one

Comment: `0 < int(x) <= 9` is true for `x = '3.14'` and `x = True`.

Comment: int(2.3) > 0 returns True but 2.3 is not a integer.